# "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[Any]'" error when trying to add array element in firestore in swift app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when trying to add an element to an existing array in firestore I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '[Any]'"

this is the method where the error occurs:

```
func addEventIdToUser(eventID: String) async {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userReference = try await db.collection("user").document(userID)
        try? await userReference.updateData(["events": FieldValue.arrayUnion(eventID)])
  
    }
```

does anyone know how to solve the issue?

Comment: you'll need to query the `events` from `userReference` and actually append it to the array first, before updating the new array in the userReference

Comment: Might be your `arrayUnion` method accepts array `[Any]` and you are trying to pass String `eventID`.

Comment: I solved the problem, brackets were missing

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I forgot brackets around eventID

this is the right way:

```
  try? await userReference.updateData(["events": FieldValue.arrayUnion([eventID])])
```